# Eigenvectors and eigendecomposition of Pauli matrices, why isn't there many?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

Say we are finding eigenvectors of $\sigma _z$, the eigenvalues are $1,-1$ so filling into the eigenvalue equation $\sigma _z (a,b)=(a,-b)=1(a,b)$ and we find that $b=0$. I am confused about why we only have (1,0) as the eigenvector, why note have $(e^{i\theta},0)$ for all $\theta$ real.

And then if we should included all these, how can we find the eigenvalue decomposition?

here I have used very bad notation $(a,b)$ should be a column vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the Pauli matrices have eigenvalues $\pm1$. The eigen-vectors in any problem are not unique up to a scale, when the vectors are defined over the real number field, or a complex scale for the complex field. The scale is removed by normalization requirements, and the overall sign (phase - factor of $\mathrm{e}^{i\theta}$) is ignored as being not of any physical consequence.

For an example of a textbook that does the eigendecomposition of the Pauli matrices (indirectly - it finds the bases and representations of the spin $1/2$ operators that are proportional to the $\sigma_i$s) see [Townsend's "A Modern Approach to
 Quantum Mechanics"](http://www.uscibooks.com/townsend3.htm).

Comment: Does this mean that compositions of a matrices are not unique?

Comment: @Spudnick you mean eigendecompositions? No, they're not. In general, it's expressing a matrix as a similarity transform,
$$M= A^{-1}\Lambda A$$
where $A$ becomes an orthogonal matrix if the eigenvectors are all orthogonal and if they're scaled by the Euclidean norm. That still leaves sign flips  (phases) on the eigenvectors. That said, these changes make no difference in the physics.
There are also [tons of other ways to decompose a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition).

Answer (score 2):

For $+1$ eigenvalue you have the equation for the respective eigenvector $(a,\,b)$:
$$
(+1)\times(a,\,b) = (a,\,-b) \implies (a,\,b)\propto(1,0) 
$$

For $-1$ eigenvalue you have the equation for the respective eigenvector $(a,\,b)$:
$$
(-1)\times(a,\,b) = (a,\,-b) \implies (a,\,b)\propto(0,1)
$$

Note that the equations determine the eigenvectors up to a scaling. We only need a proportionality relation to be obeyed. So, you can multiply eigenvector by a scalar and it will be still an eigenvector. With this you conclude that any vector in this space can be decomposed into a sum of two eigenvectors:
$$
(a,\,b)=(a,\,0)+(0,\,b)
$$

since $(a,\,0)\propto(1,\,0)$ and $(0,\,b)\propto(0,\,1)$.

Now, if this eigenvectors are representing a quantum state, we should normalize them. For the matter of convenience, is better to work with an orthonornal basis right a way, i.e.

$$
\mathcal{B}=\{|+\rangle=(e^{i\theta_{+}},\,0),\,|-\rangle = (0,\,e^{i\theta_{-}})\}
$$
where $\theta_{\pm}$ arbitrary real number that should be gauged away (this is why there is half-integer spins, and [protective representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_representation) in general).

Then, every physical state can be written as:

$$
|\psi\rangle = a|+\rangle + b|-\rangle
$$

and the normalization condition for a physical state is translated to $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$.

Comment: Good answer. Just a side note, you've got liberty to pick $a$ and $b$ what you want, but unless the specific problem doesn't allow to, you should always pick the easiest form: 1 and 0. That's because (1) it is normalized and (2) they are non negative real numbers. Normalization imposes it to be (1,0), and yes, you've got freedom to choose any $\theta$, but since it has no physical meaning... why not taking it easy?

Comment: @FGSUZ, thank for the complement. I gonna edit my own answer.